# Counting the character recursively

Tags: python, recursion

```
def count_m_recursive(sentence):
    s = len(sentence) 
    if s == 0:
        return 0
    elif sentence[0] == 'm':
        return 1
    else:
        return count_m_recursive(sentence[1:s-1]
```

This is my code. So if `count_m_recursive('my oh my')` I should get 2

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: How on earth do you expect that code to return `2`? I mean.... *there is not even a sum there*! That function always and *only* returns `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two things are wrong:

1. You are cutting off the *last* character on each recursive call:

   ```
   return count_m_recursive(sentence[1:s-1])
   ```

   Don't limit the call to `s-1`, the end index is *not* included.
2. You don't want to ignore the rest of the text when you find an `m` at the start; your version returns `1` and *ignores the rest of the string*.

Your function works with:

```
elif sentence[0] == 'm':
    return 1 + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
else:
    return count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
```

or, simplified:

```
def count_m_recursive(sentence):
    if not sentence:  # an empty string tests false
        return 0
    return (1 if sentence[0] == 'm' else 0) + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
```

or even use the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True` is 1, `False` is 0:

```
def count_m_recursive(sentence):
    if not sentence:  # an empty string tests false
        return 0
    return (sentence[0] == 'm') + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> def count_m_recursive(sentence):
...     if not sentence:  # an empty string tests false
...         return 0
...     return (sentence[0] == 'm') + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
... 
>>> count_m_recursive('my oh my')
2
```

Answer (score 12):

For the fun, you can write the entire thing as an anonymous lambda expression as follows:

```
def make_funny_func():
    # wrapped the code with return clause to emphasize that it is 
    # anonymous ;)
    return (
        # Y combinator
        (lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda a: y(y)(a))))
        # our function wrapped
        (lambda count:
            lambda s:
                # return 1 + f(s[1:]) if the first character is 'm'
                # 0 + f(s[1:]) otherwise.
                (s[0] == 'm') + count(s[1:])
                # but do the thing before only if s is non-empty string
                if s
                # else return 0
                else 0
        )
    )

count_m_recursive = make_funny_func()
print(count_m_recursive('mmmkay'))
```

Peer pessure badge, here we come ;-)

Comment: interesting, Can you explain `(lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda a: y(y)(a)))` form me.  `(lambda x: x(x))(` and `y(y)(a))` parts are very complex to me :(

Comment: You can do the same thing with just `count_m_recursive = lambda sentence: (sentence[0] == 'm') + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:]) if sentence else 0`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: it is just the Y combinator function, allows one to do recursive anonymous function (a function that can call itself without knowing its name.

Comment: It's as cool as counter-pythonic if you know what I mean :). +1

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Read about [lambda-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) in particular about [fixed-points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Recursion_and_fixed_points) (`Y` is just **a** possible fixed-point operator).

Comment: By the way: an other fixed-point operator is the following: `U = λ a b c d e f g i m n o p x t. t (i a m a f i x e d p o i n t); Y = U U U U U U U U U U U U U` which is quite funny...

Comment: When you write that in python, it stops being funny :D

Comment: @Bakuriu, AnttiHaapala: thanks, I will try to explore it further.

Answer (score 6):

```
def count_m_recursive(sentence): #mmmm
    if not sentence:
        return 0
    m_first = 1 if sentence[0] == 'm' else 0
    return m_first + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])
```

To outline some issues in current implementation:

1. No need to calculate length of a string to check if it's empty. Empty strings are equivivalent to `False` in boolean "context" (e.g. `not s` is true if `s` is empty or `None`)
2. You don't sum up occurences of the `m` in a string, so there should be some `count_so_far + recursive_call()`. In your case, since you examine string char by char `count_so_far` is 1 if current char is `m`, 0 otherwise.
3. Proper slicing to get the all the string except first N chars would be `string[N:]`. There's a [good explanation of slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) on SO

Also, this is a perfect example of [tail recursive algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Such kinds of algorithms can be expressed as a loop with advantage of executing in one call stack frame. Note that a lot of compilers optimize tail recursion to loop anyway (but that's not true for python interpreter).

Comment: Python does not optimize tail recursion; you'd explicitly use a loop instead. The dynamic nature of Python prevents optimization (the code could self-alter in more ways than I could count).

Comment: But in my experience this is homework; the OP is asked to write a recursive function to learn about recursive programming, not to optimize away the recursion, at least *not yet*. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not familiar with intrinsics of CPython to confidently state anything about optimizations it can or can't do, but I think I can trust your word on it. And I think I put this note on the wrong list, it shouldn't be seen as "issue", it's more of a general fact.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with

1. `elif sentence[0] == 'm':`
2. `slicing off last char with sentence[1:-1]`

// Note Boolean is derived class of integer class

```
def count_m_recursive(sentence):
    return (sentence or 0 ) and ((sentence[0] == 'm') + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:]))
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters how about this now ?

Comment: Ah, no, indeed, missed the `and`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I don't always recurse, I stop when sentence is empty. - sentence or 0 return 0 in last iteration

Comment: Can't say I am a fan of the one-liner; but in this case `len(sentence) or (sentence[0] == 'm') + count_m_recursive(sentence[1:])` would 'read' better.